# D3 visualization on top of a kerberized HBase cluster using Apache Phoenix

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, hbase, apache-phoenix

I want to do reporting/Visualization on top of secured Kerberos Hbase Hortonworks cluster using Apache Phoenix.

We want to use D3 visualization for reporting, I am planning to use node.js with D3, but I don't find any relevant node.js package to connect secured Hbase using Apache Phoenix.

If anyone of you implemented such pipeline, please give some direction.

Comment: you may look at https://github.com/fuwaneko/node-protobuf and refer to https://calcite.apache.org/docs/avatica_protobuf_reference.html

Comment: finally did it, pl refer below url for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762179/node-js-and-npm-phoenix-client-package-connectivity-with-kerberized-apache-phoen